# Cannot import colour presets into iTerm 2

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, colors, iterm2

Long time user of the standard terminal, short term user of iTerm 2. I've found a colour preset I want to use, however after importing them when I select them from Preferences > profiles > load presets > 'preset_name' it does not change anything.

I can use the included colour schemes just fine.

I've already tried including specific lines into my .bash_profile. Here is my current .bash_profile:

```
# Added by install_latest_perl_osx.pl
[ -r /Users/Adam/.bashrc ] && source /Users/Adam/.bashrc

# Set CLICOLOR if you want Ansi Colors in iTerm2
export CLICOLOR=1

# Set colors to match iTerm2 Terminal Colors
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Then trying to source .bashrc I get the following:

```
__perlbrew_set_path:export:2: not valid in this context: /usr/local/bin
```

At which point none of my alias' contained in my .zshrc work until I restart iTerm 2

Any ideas?

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36240185/3776858